# my modified php mail function doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a website with a contact form and it the form sends the data to my .php file via POST method. I tried a very simple script from a tutorial and it works perfectly fine. So my host doesn't seem to be a problem. But as soon as I modified the basic script and put in my own variables it stopped working. It doesn't show any syntax error and the 'name' properties from the .html file are all correct.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['sendbtn'])) {
        $to = "test@test.com";
        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $unternehmen = $_POST['Unternehmen'];
        $strasse = $_POST['Strasse'];
        $hausnummer = $_POST['Hausnummer'];
        $postleitzahl = $_POST['Postleitzahl'];
        $ort = $_POST['Ort'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $telefonnummer = $_POST['Telefonnummer'];
        $nachricht = $_POST['Nachricht'];
        $einverstaendniserklaerung = $_POST['Einverstaendiserklaerung'];
        $subject = "Das Kontaktformular wurde ausgefüllt";
        $email_body = "Neue Nachricht:\n";

        $email_body .= "Name: $name\n";
        $email_body .= "Unternehmen: $unternehmen\n";
        $email_body .= "Strasse: $strasse\n";
        $email_body .= "Hausnummer: $hausnummer\n";
        $email_body .= "Postleitzahl: $postleitzahl\n";
        $email_body .= "Ort: $ort\n";
        $email_body .= "E-Mail: $email\n";
        $email_body .= "Telefonnummer: $telefonnummer\n";
        $email_body .= "Nachricht: $nachricht\n";
        $email_body .= "Einverstaendniserklaerung: 
                        $einverstaendniserklaerung\n";

        mail($to, $subject, $email_body);
        header("Location: kontakt.html?mailsend");
    }
?>
```

This here is the working tutorial snippet:

```
<?php

   if (isset($_POST['sendbtn1'])) {
      $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
      $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
      $userName = $_POST['userName'];

      $mailTo = "test@test.com";
      $headers = "From: ".$userName;
      $txt = "Cheese: ".$firstName." ".$lastName."\n\n Ham";

      mail($mailTo, $headers, $txt);
      header("Location: index.html?mailsend");
   }
```

Comment: its probably showing you a 500 in the apache (or whatever log), possibly an undefined member in `$_POST`.

Comment: Remove the `location(…` line and see if is there some error.

Comment: can you put up the "properly working test" that you said was fine?  So we have something to compare to.

Comment: okay i added the tutorial snippet. and it's just an empty page, no errors. location removal doesn't work either. i'm wondering right now if the 'name' property in html is maybe case sensitive and that's why it doesn't work? I'll check

Comment: The Mail Headers (the 2nd argument of the `mail()` function) Is where you put things like the From Address and the Mail Subject, explicitly stating what each line is supposed to be.  Try replacing the line `$subject = "Das Kontaktformular wurde ausgefüllt";` with `$headers = "Subject:  Das Kontaktformular wurde ausgefüllt\n";  $headers .= "From:  test@test.com\n";`, and then change the call to mail to be `mail($to, $headers, $email_body);`

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time. I really appreciate that. I found the issue. It was the first if-statement that checked the 'sendbtn'. I used an 'id' instead of a 'name' property in my html.